# How to get rid of bad scrapers by CAPTCHA in Laravel?

Tags: web-scraping, laravel-4, captcha

if someone wants to load my page in his server, I want to block it. But I cannot figure out a way.

For example, someone can load a page and can get components of the page ( file_get_contents($url) ). This is so basic example.

Let me give you an example too. Open a new php file in your local server. And try this

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/alisveris-bilgisayar-notebook-dizustu-hp-compaq-cq61-3gb-ram-320-hdd-180232745/detay');
echo $file;
```

There are many libraries on internet. For example [this lib for php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).
You can also try to **scrape** web pages with that library. I will give you an example code.

```
 $url = 'http://www.sahibinden.com/bilgisayar-notebook-dizustu-bilgisayar?hasSecureTrade=true';
    include('lib.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    foreach ($html->find('td.searchResultsSmallThumbnail a') as $a) {
        $details = new simple_html_dom();
        $details->load_file('http://www.sahibinden.com'.$a->href);
        foreach ($details->find('div.classifiedDetail h1') as $headers) {
            echo $headers;
        }
    }
```

Run the script a few times. and you will not get anything.

That web page will block your script with captcha after a few times reloading the page. You can try it. I just want to know how to do it in laravel for my web page.

I searched about it over the internet, but I couldn't find anything. How can I block scraping scripts in Laravel ?

Comment: Have you really searched ? [Potential](https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha) [solutions](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha).

Comment: I just want to protect the web page from web scraping scripts. if someone wants to load page contents ( For example file_get_contents($url) ), I want to know how to block the script in Laravel.

Comment: Rather than captchas you should probably implement some rate limiting, like 2 requests/second maximum. Or user agent filtering (trivial to bypass but that'll block the occasional bot that doesn't bother to spoof its UA).

Comment: There are many web scraping scripts over internet. I want to let google do it but not other robots not other scrapers. You will probably tell me .htaccess or robots.txt is solution. But It is not what I want.

Comment: What if I make a bot that pretends to be Google ? How would you tell the difference between the real Google and some random bot that spoofs Google Bot's UA ?

Comment: Well. I don't know the difference :) But that web page maybe using script like you said to me "2 requests/second maximum". So do you have a suggestion for it ? How can do time limit between requests for a specific user or ip in laravel ?

Comment: See [here](http://fideloper.com/laravel-http-middleware) about rate limiting.

Comment: Also see [this](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle/blob/2.0/README.md) package.